# Code consolidation vs complexity

Tags: javascript

I have certain modules which handle user actions - they are Control Modules.  There were 6, Now there are 5 as I consolidated 2 which were very similar into a Module called Control

What I noticed is that as I consolidate similar code....it becomes a tad bit less efficient.  For example in Control I now have an extra logical statement to determine program flow.

```
if( this.type === 'signup' && !this.text_object.checkPattern( 'name' ) )
```

This simple line allowed me to combine ControlSignIn and ControlSignUp as the only difference was checking the name in Sign Up which Sign In did not have.

I can continue in this manner and I get more complex code but my code footprint is smaller.

There is a trade-off between ( complexity and run time ) vs ( code foot print ).

I'm guessing it does not matter but I just wanted to make sure.

As an example I put in `ControlTweet` which I could also fit to `Control.`

Question?

Should I consolidate ControlTweet with Control?

In general, where do you draw the line or is it a matter of preference?

**Control**

```
/**
 *Control - receives incoming requests for client use
 */

var Control = ( function () 
{
    var Control = function ( type )
    {
        this.TIME = 4000;
        this.type = type;
        this.form_element = document.getElementById( type ), 
        this.response_element = document.getElementById( type + '_response' );

        this.text_object = new TextValidator( this.form_element ),
        this.message_object = new Message( this.response_element ),
        this.effects_object= new Effects( this.response_element );
    };
    Control.prototype.invoke = function( ) 
    {
        if( Global.validate_input_on === 1 )
        {
            if( !this.text_object.checkEmpty() ) 
            {
                this.message_object.display( 'empty' );
                this.effects_object.fade( 'down', this.TIME );
                return false;
            }
            if( this.type === 'signup' && !this.text_object.checkPattern( 'name' ) ) 
            {
                this.message_object.display( 'name' );
                this.effects_object.fade( 'down', this.TIME );
                return false;
            }
            if( !this.text_object.checkPattern( 'email' ) ) 
            {
                this.message_object.display( 'email' );
                this.effects_object.fade( 'down', this.TIME );
                return false;
            }
            if( !this.text_object.checkPattern( 'pass' ) ) 
            {
                this.message_object.display( 'pass' );
                this.effects_object.fade( 'down', this.TIME );
                return false;
           }
        }
        var response_element = this.response_element;
        new Ajax().invoke( serializeArray( this.form_element ) + '&ajax_type=' + this.type + '_control', function( server_response_text ) { ajaxType( server_response_text, response_element, 'respond' ); } );
    };
    Control.in = function()
    {
        new Control( 'signin' ).invoke();
    };
    Control.up = function()
    {
        new Control( 'signup' ).invoke();
    };
    Control.out = function()
    {
        new Ajax().invoke( '&ajax_type=ControlSignOut', function( server_response_text ) { ajaxType( server_response_text, 0, 'simple' ); } );
    };
    Control.try = function()
    {
        new Ajax().invoke( '&ajax_type=ControlTryIt', function( server_response_text ) { ajaxType( server_response_text, 0, 'simple' ); } );
    };
    return Control;
} () );
```

**ControlTweet**

```
/**
 *    ControlTweet
 */

function interfaceTweet()
{
    var fill_element = document.getElementById( 'tweet_fill' ),
        form_element = document.getElementById( 'tweet' ),
        response_element = document.getElementById( 'tweet_response' );

    var text_object = new TextValidator( form_element ),
        message_object = new Message( response_element ),
        effects_object = new Effects( response_element );

    if( Global.validate_input_on === 1 )
    {
        if( !text_object.checkEmpty() ) 
        {
            message_object.display( 'empty' );
            effects_object.fade( 'down', 4000 );
            return;
        }

        if( !text_object.checkPattern( 'tweet' ) ) 
        {
            message_object.display( 'tweet' );
            effects_object.fade( 'down', 4000 );
            return;
        }
    }
    new Ajax().invoke( serializeArray( form_element ) + '&ajax_type=ControlTweet_add', function( server_response_text ) { ajaxType( server_response_text, response_element, 'tweet', fill_element ); } );
}
```

**What I ended up using:**

```
/**
 *Control - receives incoming requests for client use
 */

var Control = ( function () 
{
    var Control = function ( type )
    {
        this.TIME = 4000;
        this.type = type;

        this.form_element = document.getElementById( type ), 
        this.response_element = document.getElementById( type + '_response' );
        if( type === 'tweet' ) { this.fill_element = document.getElementById( type + '_fill' ); }

        this.text_object = new TextValidator( this.form_element ),
        this.message_object = new Message( this.response_element ),
        this.effects_object= new Effects( this.response_element );
    };
    Control.prototype.invoke = function( ) 
    {
        if( Global.validate_input_on === 1 )
        {
            if( !this.text_object.checkEmpty() ) 
            {
                this.message_object.display( 'empty' );
                this.effects_object.fade( 'down', this.TIME );
                return false;
            }
            switch( this.type )
            {
                case 'signin':
                    if( !this.text_object.checkPattern( 'email' ) ) 
                    {
                        this.message_object.display( 'email' );
                        this.effects_object.fade( 'down', this.TIME );
                        return false;
                    }
                    if( !this.text_object.checkPattern( 'pass' ) ) 
                    {
                        this.message_object.display( 'pass' );
                        this.effects_object.fade( 'down', this.TIME );
                        return false;
                    }
                    break;
                case 'signup':
                    if( !this.text_object.checkPattern( 'email' ) ) 
                    {
                        this.message_object.display( 'email' );
                        this.effects_object.fade( 'down', this.TIME );
                        return false;
                    }
                    if( !this.text_object.checkPattern( 'name' ) ) 
                    {
                        this.message_object.display( 'name' );
                        this.effects_object.fade( 'down', this.TIME );
                        return false;
                    }
                    if( !this.text_object.checkPattern( 'pass' ) ) 
                    {
                        this.message_object.display( 'pass' );
                        this.effects_object.fade( 'down', this.TIME );
                        return false;
                    }
                    break;
                case 'tweet':
                    if( !this.text_object.checkPattern( 'tweet' ) ) 
                    {
                        this.message_object.display( 'tweet' );
                        this.effects_object.fade( 'down', this.TIME );
                        return false;
                    }
                    break;
                default:
            }
        }
        var response_element = this.response_element;
        if( this.type === 'tweet' ) { var fill_element = this.fill_element; }
        new Ajax().invoke( serializeArray( this.form_element ) + '&ajax_type=' + this.type + '_control', function( server_response_text ) { ajaxType( server_response_text, response_element, 'respond', fill_element ); } );
    };
    Control.tweet = function()
    {
        new Control( 'tweet' ).invoke();
    }
    Control.in = function()
    {
        new Control( 'signin' ).invoke();
    };
    Control.up = function()
    {
        new Control( 'signup' ).invoke();
    };
    Control.out = function()
    {
        new Ajax().invoke( '&ajax_type=ControlSignOut', function( server_response_text ) { ajaxType( server_response_text, 0, 'simple' ); } );
    };
    Control.try = function()
    {
        new Ajax().invoke( '&ajax_type=ControlTryIt', function( server_response_text ) { ajaxType( server_response_text, 0, 'simple' ); } );
    };
    Control.bookmarkDelete = function( event_pull )
    {
        event_pull.preventDefault();
        domBookmarkDelete( this );
        new Ajax().invoke( encodeURIComponent( this.name ) + "=" + encodeURIComponent( this.innerHTML ) + '&ajax_type=ControlBookmark_delete', function( ) { } );
    }
    return Control;
} () );
```

Comment: This is, to me, a fascinating question. The problem I have, though, is that there is unlikely to be a single 'correct' answer, given that it's more of a discussion topic. As such it's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) for Stack Overflow. Perhaps [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) might be a better home?

Comment: I would say the correct answer it there is a line that is subjective and determined by the programmer and specs....defining it as subjective as opposed to objective is an answer for me as it validates what I was thinking.i.e. that is nobody came in and said this is the correct answer in a sense answered the question.

Comment: I have a simple rule. If I'm going to make the code harder to change. Why I'm doing it better make more money than not doing so....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty subjective question in the sense that everyone will have their own personal preference when it comes to consolidating code, and it is also localized as it can vary from project to project. That being said, there is obviously a line to be drawn because you don't want everything consolidated to one massive `main()` function that handles everything and then some.

There are two programming rules of thumb which should help you out:

1. DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself)
2. Premature optimization === evil

Now, the DRY principle states that--when reasonable--you should combine similar code into reusable modules. The keyword here being similar code, as it sometimes it makes sense for you to have multiple separate modules even at the risk of repeating code. The reason being is that you also have to account for code maintenance and readability, and it can become a readability nightmare when you start consolidating dissimilar modules in the name of DRY.

I also mentioned premature optimization because you brought up the idea small footprint versus code complexity. I suggest you forget about that and leave the code footprint to compressing/gzipping.

To finally answer your question, I would personally combine the modules. However, that should ultimately be your decision as you are the one who has to maintain that code. **Just remember to properly comment and document everything so you aren't lost in the dark when you revisit this months later.**

Answer (score 1):

Code should be producing results you want, readable, testable and have **required performance** irrespective of language.

You trying to find a trade off  between subjective "readable" and unnecessary "absolutely fastest". I'd say - whatever is readable for **you** is good, unless you getting issues with meeting **required performance** (must have measurements/goals first...).

Answer (score 1):

The answer is inheritance.  Take the common parts and put them in a parent class and then inherit them in.  Putting in a bunch of if statements for different calls is sort of like an inheritance hack.  Once I learn how to do this in JS I'll post the code.